# Kiban,Uptime,Monitoring need to run once created for the first time then run based on the schedule

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, monitoring, heartbeat, uptime-monitoring

using elastic stack version 7.17.0,
on heartbeat monitoring, I can't configure the monitor to run once it created
for example:

- type: http
- schedule: '@every 5s'
- urls: ["http://myhost:80"]

this configuration will run every 5 seconds after the creation of the monitor but I want it to run once created then run every 5 seconds

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code is what I mentioned  `type, schedule, URL`  which represents monitor data, but I need to make this monitor run once created first then run on every 5 seconds